# DropdownListFor default value with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DropdownList that I am creating using the below code. It is not setting the default "Select Product/Program..." text in the dropdown. If I remove the ng-model then it sets it correctly. Anybody has any idea about how to approach this issue.

```
     @Html.FormDropDownListFor(m => m.ProductTypeId, new SelectList(EnumExtensions.GetSelectionList<ProductType>(), "Value", "Name"), "Select Product/Program...", new {id = "SelectedProductType",tabindex = tabIndex++,ng_model = "selectProductTypeModel"})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this..setting the model value in the controller to be empty `$scope.selectProductTypeModel = ' ';` sets it to the default value.

Answer (score 0):

if you tried to inspect the dropdownlist you'll find that your default selection has empty string as a value so  add `ng_init="selectProductTypeModel=''"`in order to select the one who has empty string as a value
as follows:

```
@Html.FormDropDownListFor(m => m.ProductTypeId, new SelectList(EnumExtensions.GetSelectionList<ProductType>(), "Value", "Name"), "Select Product/Program...", new {id = "SelectedProductType",tabindex = tabIndex++,ng_model = "selectProductTypeModel",ng_init="selectProductTypeModel='' "})
```